# isUserInteractionEnabled = false still allows double tap gesture

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have created a double tap gesture for my Collection View.  When a cell in the Collection View is double tapped i disable user interaction to the cell.  This stops me being able to single tap that cell while a process runs.  However i can still double tap that cell which runs the process again.  I still want double tap to be available for other cells in the collection, i just want to disable it for the cell that is running process. When the process is finished user interaction is turned back on, and hopefully double tap also.

So this is how i define double tap, in viewDidLoad of the View Controller holding the Collection View:

```
    // add gesture recogniser
    let doubleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didDoubleTap))
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        doubleTap.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
```

And I'm just switching userInteraction as usual when needed depending on state of process.

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Im not sure how to approach this as if i disable the double tap gesture for the Collection View i cant double tap other cells.  And i don't even know how to set it up so that double tap is only available in the cell and not the Collection View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling `isUserInteractionEnabled` on any subview of your `collectionView` will still pass events to the `collectionView` (superview). So `isUserInteractionEnabled` disables touch events on all subviews but not on superviews, which in this case is the collectionView.

You have a few options to proceed:

1. Create a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to handle the double tap internally and then delegate the double tap event.
2. Within the `didDoubleTap` method check to see if the cell that you just double tapped is enabled/disabled. You can do this by using `indexPathForItemAtPoint:` and then `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thanks, i went the easy option straight up and used the if statement.  This seems to be disabling the tap gesture for the cells that were visible when the first double tap took place.  Ill look into the delegate method.

Comment: Actually it does work, i just had my conditionals out of whack.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `isEnabled` to false on the gesture recognizer.

You could implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and return false from `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`.